# What Does the Abbreviation NSX Stand for in VMware NSX for vSphere?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, vmware-nsx

This may be better suited for a Networking Exchange, but as I have no desire to join that group I wanted to try SuperUser first.

The title pretty much says it all. I've recently begun diving into VMware's Software Defined Data Center (SDDC) and the acronym NSX appears to be almost synonymous with this. Just as it would be difficult to learn about (SDDC) without knowing what SDDC actually stands for I must also find out what NSX stands for.

To be clear on this, I am not looking for a generic answer such as "*VMware NSX is a virtual networking and security software product family created from... bla bla bla...*" I'm well versed in Google Queries myself. What I am looking for is exactly what the acronym (NSX) stands for- N.... S.... X.....

**NOTE:** I'm not entirely convinced that (NSX) actually stands for anything, however the thought of an IT company labeling a product as such without any real reasoning is both troubling and frustrating, so I figured I'd reach out to the community before silently cursing under breath. Hopefully someone is able to uncover the mystery that can't.

Comment: I can't seem to find a definite source as to what NSX directly mean, but NS seems to stand for Network Security and the X for eXtendibility/eXtended (or alike).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not pertain to anything about the software. Knowing what the acronym exactly means doesn't provide any useful value.

Comment: "Knowing what the acronym exactly means doesn't provide any useful value"

Aside from this being one of the dumbest statements I've heard, I can assure you that if it's something I'm curious about, than others are too. Always get a kick out of seeing the "closed as off-topic" questions receiving the highest views.

Comment: Hey, imagine that, I got a popular question badge for my question that "provides no useful value". Proving once again that the idiots who close these topics don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: Today I have spent approx 20 minutes to find out what does NSX means also ... as a human the meaningful things are more easily capturable understandable ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSX doesn't really stand for anything.

> the thought of an IT company labeling a product as such without any real reasoning is both troubling and frustrating,

"ESX" in VMware ESX Server and "GSX" in VMware GSX Server did not (officially) stand for anything.  It stands to reason that NSX doesn't stand for anything either and was named to sound similar to those, and the N was probably chosen since it's a networking product.

---

*Unofficially*, [ESX stood for "Elastic Sky"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESXi) and [GSX stood for "Ground Storm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Server#Naming), and the "X" was tacked on to sound more mysterious/cool/trendy.  Those were the initial names that some marketing folks figuratively pulled out of a hat, but they were quickly abandoned, and they were always meaningless.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I came across the following resource which confirms your answer. And although it doesn't specifically address NSX, it does in fact prove that VMware's product naming convention is nonsensical. I appreciate your time and effort on this James. It was driving me nuts. 

http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2010/07/29/vmware-related-acronyms/

Answer (score 1):

NSX is a brand name and likely only barely an acronym, and stands for VMware's Network Virtualization and Security Platform: https://www.vmware.com/products/nsx.htm.

X is likely a generic wildcard that could mean "virtualization" or "platform", both uses I've seen before elsewhere. LPChip's comment about it being about Extensibility is also very likely.